# How make paypal adaptive payments using credit card of payment sender?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I want to receive money by credit card number and to distribute between multiple users. I want to use paypal API for this task. Is this possible? If so, how?

I have explored the paypal adaptive payment method, but that uses IPN method, and sending the user to his paypal account page. I want to use a credit card method of payment for sender / buyer.I do not want to send him to paypal account page.

Comment: One of the major points of using Paypal is that customers only have to trust Paypal, not some more or less obscure sites on Internet with their credit card information. You can't do what you're asking for with Paypal.

Comment: You'll have to send them through the PayPal checkout pages, but if you're using a primary receiver then it should offer "guest checkout" which allows people to pay with a credit card without signing in to an account.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Chained Payment in Adaptive Payment. By right it would offer you the guest payment. But in order to make the payments with credit card go through without any problem, all the receiver should be a verified Premier or Verified Business Account.